is my attempt correct? proof that L in P or in NPC? $L=\{G$ is an undirected graph on n vertices VC $U$ and an IS $I$ such that $|U|+|I|=n+10$ \}
I am facing a problem with the validity of the reduction function, may I get some assist in solving this issue, please?
$L=\{<G>| G$ is an undirected graph on n vertices that has a Vertex Cover $U$ and an Independent Set $I$ such that $|U|+|I|=n+10$ }
proof that L is in NPC or P or neither:
my attempt:
the language belongs to NPC,
first, let's describe an accepting nondeterministic turning machine.
N on input :

guess a set $U$, -- O(n)
check that it is a vertex cover (check each edge and make sure one vertex is in the set)  else reject. -- O(n^2)
guess a set $I$ -- O(n)
make sure it is indeed an independent set(no edges between nodes in the set $I$) else reject --- -- O(n^2)
make sure $U$+$I$ = $n+10$ else reject -- O(1)
accept -- O(1)

correctness:
$<G>\in L$ then it has a vertex cover $U$ and Independent set $I$ such that it will match all steps and the machine will accept in step 6 on some calculation branch.
$<G>\notin L$ then it may not have an independent set, or a vertex cover, or $U$+$I$ $neq n+10$ then the machine will reject on all calculation branches the machine will reject.
polynomial time:
Note runtimes on each step $\rightarrow$ $O(n^2)$ which is polynomial in the size of the input 
Reduction from an NPC Language:
$VC \leq_p L $
 --> <G'>
where <G'> has + 10 nodes with no edges connected to them.
the reduction is complete as it is defined for every input,
can be computed - just adding 10 nodes and encoding the graph, and valid and polinomal in the size of the input as it is just adding 10 nodes:
**validity:

$<G>\in L$ then there is a vertex cover of size $U$
......**

I feel that I am wrong here, is there someone that may know what the reduction should be like?

https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/check-my-answer/info, https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/597/755

then why every time i publish a question every one asking me what I tried and where did I get stuck? @D.W.

Neither "Here is an exercise-style problem/task, please show me the solution" nor "Here is an exercise-style problem/task, here is my attempted solution, is my solution correct?" are good questions here.  This site is designed as a place where people can collaborate to build an archive/library of knowledge that will be useful to others in the future... in the format of high-quality questions and answers.  See https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98 and https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/ and https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/.

but how I will be able to get to high quality questions without good understanding of the basics?

This site might not be the right resource if you can't get to high quality questions.  The site might not be the right place for everyone.  There are many ways to learn the basics: read textbooks, take online courses, seek one-on-one tutoring, etc.  If in the process of studying the basics you are able to identify a good conceptual question that others studying the same topic might have, you can ask about that.  As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on.

but i dont have money for one-on-one tutoring, nor someone that know the answers, only few people in the world learn this topic and become good at it to teach it.
the web is can be used for knowledge sharing and helping others , I don't belive what you are saying, this website needs to be like stack overflow

I understand.  That's difficult.  Nonetheless, our site is not designed to help with that problem.  We have a particular focus, and we have site standards that we must uphold, to preserve this space.  See https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1151/755.  You might be surprised about Stack Overflow's purpose.  See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/429808/781723, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254770/781723, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/395221/160917, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/781723.

Recall that if $I\in V(G)$ is an independent set of $G$ then $V(G)\setminus I$ is a vertex cover of $G$ and vice versa. Now let $I$ be the maximum independent set and $U'$ be the minimum vertex cover. Then we have $|U'|+|I|=n$. Thus, if we can simply add $10$ more vertices into $U'$ make it bigger ($U$) and satisfy the given requirement. Moreover, this is the only way you can satisfy the requirement $|U|+|I|=n+10$. Thus, the task boils down to deciding whether the minimum vertex cover of $G$ is at most $n-10$. Alternatively, we can ask whether there exists an independent set of size larger than $10$. This can be decided in polynomial time, even with an exhaustive search over $n\choose 10$ choices. Thus, your language $L$ is in $P$.

thank you a lot !

can you explain then later on, how the it is in P? we added the 10 vertexes and then why after this reduction it is in P ?

All you need to do here is evaluate ${n}\choose{10}$ $= O(n^{10})$ choices. The evaluation would be linear in the size of the graph.
